# Turn off auto 301 on archive pages?

Tags: plugin-wp-seo-yoast, infinite-scroll

I'm currently using [infinite-scroll](https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll).
The scroll ends when it reaches a 404.
For example it will look for

- category/cars/page/2
- category/cars/page/3
- etc

until it hits a 404. The problem is that infinite scroll keeps on loading the first page of content because instead of a 404, I'm getting a 301.

I also have yoast enabled.

Any idea on how to fix this?

pretty sure it's yoast although I'm not sure how to turn off the auto 301 setting.

Answer (score 1):

This is known bug.

You can read something about this here:

- https://github.com/Yoast/wordpress-seo/issues/1109

[michaelcurry](https://github.com/michaelcurry) there wrote a solution.

> Quick Fix - Put this into your functions file.

```
add_action('wp_loaded', 'remove_actions');

function remove_actions()
{
    remove_action( 'wp', array( $GLOBALS['wpseo_front'], 'pagination_overflow_redirect' ), 99 );
}
```